# Calling function from another file declared in a header file

Tags: c, function, external

I want to call a function that is in sin.c, and the main file is in test1.c

and the files look like this:

file test1.c:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "sin.h"

    int main(){
       float angle;
       double sinValue;

       printf("Please enter a angle: ");
       scanf("%f", &angle);

       sinValue = sin(angle);

       printf("the sin value of this angle is: %2.7f.", sinValue);
       printf("program terminated");

       return 0;
    }
```

this is the header file:

In sin.h:

```
extern double sin(float angle);
```

In file sin.c:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define EPSILON 0.0000001;

int fact(int n);

double sin(float angle){

    float rad;
    float pi = M_PI;
    double newSin, oldSin;
    double n = 1.0;
    double token;


    //find the radians
    rad = angle * M_PI / 180.0;
    newSin = rad;

    //find the approxmate value of sin(x)
    while((newSin - oldSin) > EPSILON ){

        oldSin = newSin;
        token = 2.0 * n - 1.0;
        newSin = oldSin + pow(-1.0, n) * pow(rad, token) / fact(token);
        n++;
    }

    return newSin;
}
```

The problem is when I compile the test1.c the error message shows:

```
sin.h:1:15: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘sin’      [enabled by default]
 extern double sin(float angle);
               ^
/tmp/ccxzixfm.o: In function `main':
test1.c:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `sin'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test1] Error 1
```

It is already declared in the header file and I also included that header file, so what is the error. I'm so confused.

Thanks before, John.

I use the "make" command to compile the test1.c

Here is the compilation process:

```
zxz111@ubuntu:~/Desktop/sin$ ls
sin.c  sin.c~  sin.h  test1.c  test1.c~
zxz111@ubuntu:~/Desktop/sin$ make test1
cc     test1.c   -o test1
In file included from test1.c:3:0:
sin.h:1:15: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘sin’ [enabled by default]
 extern double sin(float angle);
               ^
/tmp/ccxzixfm.o: In function `main':
test1.c:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `sin'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test1] Error 1
zxz111@ubuntu:~/Desktop/sin$ make test1
```

Comment: can you show us your compilation steps.how you compiled?you need to give the definition of the function which is in sin.c also with test1.c compilation commands.you have compile both test1.c and sin.c simultaneously

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass both source files to the compiler.

If you're using GCC it would be:

```
gcc sin.c main.c -o main
```

Although your `fact()` function doesn't seem to be defined anywhere and a function named `sin()` is already defined in `<math.h>` you probably wanna rename yours.

Comment: I intentionally remove that piece, and thanks for pointing out the sin() part.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you are compiling both of the files.
So for example, if you are using g++ to compile, it would be:

```
g++ sin.c test1.c -o run
```

Answer (score 1):

**ld returned 1 exit status**:::: It is linker error. It means when your linker is searching for symbol "sin", it is not able to find.

The reason you are getting this error is(because you have not added whole sin.h, i am assuming), you have not include "sin.c" in "sin.h".

Also, Compile both files so that sin.o will get generated and from there your linker will be able to map symbol.

**warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘sin’      [enabled by default]
 extern double sin(float angle);**
Also, try to avoid function name which are already defined in standard libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Function declarations have external linkage by default. To eliminate the warning, remove `extern` from your function prototype in `sin.h`.

When you compile, compile `sin.c` first, but without linking eg. `cc -c sin.c`. This will produce an object file, probably named `sin.o`.

Then you can compile `test1.c`, linking your object file into it like so: `cc test1.c sin.o -o test1`